# c# how to get values between parentheses with regex

Tags: c#, regex

I need to use regex to search a string and then get the values between parentheses. here is an example string that I want to use regex for.

```
(BIRIM FIYAT)+(SERVICE)*(SATIŞ FİYATI)
```

I need to get the  `(BIRIM FIYAT)` and (SERVICE) and (SATIŞ FİYATI) in an array. Would you please give me an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the pattern `\(.*?\)` in C# to get a list of matches, which can then be converted to `string[]` or whatever you need.

```
string str = "(BIRIM FIYAT)+(SERVICE)*(SATIŞ FİYATI)";
string pattern = @"\(.*?\)";

Regex r = new Regex(pattern);
MatchCollection matches = r.Matches(str);
string[] vals = matches.Cast<Match>().Select(p => p.Value).ToArray();
foreach (string m in vals)
{
    Console.WriteLine(m);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out :

```
"\((\s*?.*?)*?\)"
```